HTTP 401 Unauthorized Error Even When Authorization Header Is Correctly Formatted
I am working on a .NET 8 application with JWT authentication and role-based authorization. When I test my API using Postman, it returns a successful response with status code 200. However, when I run the same request within my project, I get an HTTP 401 Unauthorized error.
Project Setup:
1..NET version: 8
2.JWT Token Configuration: The token includes claims such as sub, role, exp, iss, and aud.
3.Authorization Header: Sent as Authorization: Bearer .
My Program.cs


I got two blog posts that might help you  https://nestenius.se/net/debugging-jwtbearer-claim-problems-in-asp-net-core/ and https://nestenius.se/net/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/
